# Matrix Multiplication in C using Dynamic Allocation (Program Crashes)

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, dynamic-allocation

So as stated in the title I have a program to multiplies to matrices read from a file, but when I run it it simply crashes. I am required to have two functions to perform the multiplication and one to print the result while using pointers with no return values. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void mat_mult(int ** arr1, int rows1, int cols1, int ** arr2, 
    int rows2, int rcols2, int ** arr3);
void mat_out(int ** arr, int rows, int cols);

int main(void){
int **mat1, **mat2, **res, rows1, cols1, rows2, cols2, i, j;
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("Matrices.txt", "r");
    fscanf(f, "%d", &rows1);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &cols1);
    mat1 = (int**) malloc(rows1*sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0;i < rows1;i++){
        mat1[i] = (int*)malloc(cols1*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i = 0;i < rows1;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < cols1;j++){
            fscanf(f, "%d", &mat1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fscanf(f, "%d", &rows2);
    fscanf(f, "%d", &cols2);
    mat2 = (int**) malloc(rows2*sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0;i < rows2;i++){
        mat2[i] = (int*)malloc(cols2*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i = 0;i < rows2;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < cols2;j++){
            fscanf(f, "%d", &mat2[i][j]);
        }
    }
    res = (int**)calloc(rows1,sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0;i < rows1;i++){
        res[i] = (int*)calloc(cols2,sizeof(int));
    }
    /*mat_mult(mat1, rows1, cols1, mat2, rows2, cols2, res);
    mat_out(res, rows1, cols2);*/

}

void mat_mult(int ** mat1, int rows1, int cols1, int ** mat2, 
    int rows2, int cols2, int ** res){
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0;i < rows1;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < cols2;j++){
            res[i][j] = 0;
            for(k = 0;k < cols1;k++){
                res[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
void mat_out(int ** res, int rows, int cols){
int i, j;
    for(i = 0;i < rows;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < cols;j++){
            printf("%d ",res[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you identify where the crash happens?

Comment: One of the first things to try when your program doesn't work, and especially when it crashes mysteriously, is to run it in a debugger.  At minimum, you ought to be able to find where the crash is occurring.

Comment: However, your code looks OK to me and runs just fine (after uncommenting the calls to `mat_mult()` and `mat_out()`).  The only problem valgrind reports is failure to free the allocated memory, and that won't, in itself, cause a crash.

Comment: Are you sure you have `Matrices.txt` defined correctly?

Comment: If indeed you have a crash, then the most plausible reason is bad input.  In particular, if the second dimension of the first matrix is (read as) greater than the first dimension of the second matrix, then you'll get an out-of-bounds array access producing UB.  You really ought to validate that those are the same.  (Where I mean "matrix" in an abstract, mathematical sense.)

Comment: There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in your code. A pointer is not an array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see any errors, so I compiled and executed your program and it worked as expected, maybe your problem was the data that you added to your file `Matrices.txt`.

My file `Matrices.txt` is:

```
2
2
3
2
1
4
2
2
3
2
1
4
```

This file will produce 2 matrix with cells equal to:

```
3 2
1 4
```

And the multiplication result is:

[image]

Which is perfectly fine.

Comment: I concur.  And this is a good reason to close the question -- or at least seek clarification -- instead of answering it.

Comment: Okay great thanks. I'll take a look at my file and how I process it.